# Como subir varias rutas de imágenes al mismo campo? Laravel MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

soy nuevo en Laravel y tengo, como pueden ver en el titulo, la siguiente duda.
Tengo un objeto perro en el cual uno de los atributos es una imagen. Ya logre que con el input en el html me deje seleccionar varios archivos, pero cuando lo guardo en la DB solo entra la primera imagen seleccionada.
Hay alguna forma de declarar a ese campo como un array que contenga las distintas rutas de las imágenes? Tengo que hacer una tabla nueva exclusivamente para las imágenes?
Gracias desde ya y perdonen si pregunto algo obvio.

Comment: Estaría bueno que muestres el código para poder ver como lo estás haciendo. La vista, la ruta y el método que usas para guardar en DB

Comment: Listo! Gracias!

Comment: Ok, entonces vos mismo resolviste lo que estabas preguntando. No es por ser obsesivo, pero para seguir las reglas de stackoverflow (y que la pregunta caiga bien en la comunidad), limita la pregunta a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada. Evita hacer múltiples preguntas distintas a la vez. Podes ver la página https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para tener una mejor experiencia. En fin, te sugiero que pongas el código que agregaste como una respuesta a esta pregunta, y formules una nueva para "me falta como desplegarlas en la blade."

Comment: otra pagina que podes leer para obtener una mejor respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Dale, voy a hacer eso. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
$imgs = [];
foreach ($request->file('img') as $image) {
  $destinationPath = 'perrosimg/';
  $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
  $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
  array_push($imgs,$filename);
}
$perro->img = json_encode($imgs);
```

}

Pude guardar las rutas de las imagenes en archivo json.

Comment: Sinceramente pienso que deberías haber creado una tabla nueva para las imágenes. Esta solución no es la más apta ni la adecuada, pues rompe de plano la normalización: https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forma_normal_(base_de_datos)

Comment: ¿Quién vota positivo este tipo de respuestas? realmente es una mala idea hacer esto.